# The difference between "SDN Platform" and "SDN Controller Platform"

Tags: networking, sdn

What is the difference between "SDN Platform" and "SDN Controller Platform"? These two indicate the same things? Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much literal difference between these terms, and usually they are referred interchangeably. `SDN Controller Platform` is actually the controller software that takes care of entire network manageability.

The controller is said as a platform, as this gives the programmer the flexibility to add specific modules (for e.g., a routing module which takes care of routing only multicast packets using some very different routing algorithm) and run them on the controller. A controller when used without any specific modules, essentially sends all packets to everywhere (well, it depends on the controller implementation also). The controller is a platform where you are expected to do stuff and make your network behave the way you want.

And sometimes `SDN Platform` is used for `SDN Infrastructure` which includes topology, switches, one or more controllers and so on. Essentially describing the whole network infrastructure.

What you need to know is SDN components, like controller, switches, protocols etc.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see a exact difference between two terminologies you have mentioned .
Briefing SDN Platform simply denotes the seperation of Data plane and Control Plane . I know this can be confusing . But think it this way when you seperate the brain of a switch and put it in another layer ..
Generally SDN consists three layers (from top)

1)Applications -- Consists of Network Applications eg: FW,IPsec etc..

```
             NB API                   --- no defined Standard yet
```

2)Control --- consists of Controller

```
             SB API                  --- This is where OPENFLOW is used
```

3)Infrastructure --- consists of network devices eg:Switches

The Control Layer connects these two layes using NB API and SB API's
SDN simply gives advantage to network admin to configure multiple network devices .
Using a SDN Controller they can configure multiple network devices at a single place

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

From software perspective, the term 'platform' emphasises on how a software would be used as the enabler for other applications.

A SDN contoller can be any application which pushes policies to the underlying network. SDN platform on the other hand, should provide extended tools, APIs and hooks to facilitate running 3rd party applications on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

SDN is one of the best open-source platform for developing the projects. SDN platform is just nothing but the networking platform which provides us with numerous benefits to work on topologies. It gives a option to the user to install any controller of their choice and work on it.

SDN Controller platform is the SDN that provides a base platform for different number of controllers onto it. They work on API. SDN Controller platform architecture differs for the different controllers.